# MS Graph API get unfiltered event HTML body

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

It is documented that for messages we can specify `Prefer: outlook.allow-unsafe-html` to get original unfiltered message body content - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-create-send-messages#read-messages-with-control-over-the-body-format-returned.

When creating and then retrieving events from calendar I observe MS Graph/Outlook also filters body HTML content for this resource type meaning I am not retrieving original content I sent during create request.

I tried specifying `Prefer: outlook.allow-unsafe-html` header for `/me/events` and `/me/events/{event-id}` Graph endpoints but doesn't seem like that header is working here. Is there any way to retrieve unfiltered event body?